# FileReader doesn't read file in tomcat Server

Tags: java, tomcat

i have this code

```
  public ArrayList<String> getMail() {

        ArrayList<String> i = new ArrayList();

        try {

            int j = 0 ;

            FileReader file = new FileReader("emaillist0.txt");

            BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(file);

            String linha = lerArq.readLine();

            System.out.println("tp aqio ´prra");
            while (linha != null) {
                i.add(j, linha);
                j++;
                linha = lerArq.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(i.size());

            file.close();
            return i;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.printf( e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }
```

this problem is when i execute this code in apache tomcat throws this error

emaillist0.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)java.lang.NullPointerException
but when i execute this code in a java application work perfectly

Comment: Related, but not a part of your question: you should call `FileReader.close()` in a `finally` block.

Answer (score 1):

use absolute path instead of file's name, or move your file into bin directory of tomcat (of course it depends on your OS)

Comment: Definitely use a fully-qualified path. Don't put the file into the `bin` directory. Also, the CWD of the process isn't always the `bin` directory.